# Updated version of app not reflecting in App List in Settings, But the App is getting updated

Tags: ios, xcode

I am facing a strange issue. I have published version `1.1.0` of an app in the internal app store of my organisation. I have set the app version and build number, both as `1.1.0`.

Today, I pushed an update of the app on that store. The version and build number of the app is now `1.2.0`

Now, according to the functionality of our app, if an update is available, then on launching the old app, a popup will be shown to get that update.

So, on pressing the update button, the app is actually getting updated as the changes that we pushed in the new version is getting reflected in the updated app on my device.

However, when i am going in the `settings app -> MyApplication`, the app version still shows `1.1.0`..!!!

I have updated the version and build in Info.plist. What am i missing??

Here is the place where I have changed the Version in all the targets too:

[image]

Comment: Make sure, in your app setting also updated version. Put a breakpoint in setting and check what value you are setting for version number.

Comment: @iDeveloper as in? I am going in Settings app->App->

Comment: Is the internal app store caching the old version by chance?  Are you sure you are downloading the newest?  If you delete the app and then download again do you have the same issue?

Comment: @AndrewLombard: Yes im downloding newest.No, when i delete and install, i get updated version.

Comment: @Shradha can you post the code you are using to check the version?  Or is this done by your internal app store?  If so do you have more details on your app store?

Comment: @AndrewLombard: I am simply going into the settings app of iPhone, and checking which version is installed in the phone after update.The app gets updated, that i am sure of. However, the settings app of iPhone does not shoow the updated version.

Comment: I think i am missing something, may be some where else in plist i need to update the version too..! but not able to figure out where..!!

Comment: @Shradha do you have any extrensions in the app?  Widgets etc?  You will need to update all versions in all targets.

Comment: Please share the screenshot of app version in setting screen.

Comment: @AndrewLombard No, no extensions.. Version is updated in all targets..Targets are basically Testcases :( Updating the question with Screenshot

Comment: No need to change everywhere. Just change at one place, It will update in whole project.  Target(Select Your Project) > General > Identity > Version [Whatever you want to put]

Comment: @iDeveloper: This is what i did in the beginning.. but its not working

Comment: I think, No need to put a version number in versioning section.